# What is the python code corresponding to the following R code?

Tags: plotly, plotly-python, r-plotly, ggseasonplot

I have monthly sales for 5 years and I applied the following code In R to seasonal plot:

```
ggseasonplot(S5, year.labels=TRUE, year.labels.left=TRUE)
```

So how can I plot it using pythonic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you have not provided any sample data,  so I have used some order data
- really you are structuring data using standard **pandas** concepts https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html
- then simple case of generating **line** figure

```
import pandas as pd
import io, requests
import plotly.express as px

# use requests so that there are no issues with utf-8 encoding
df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        requests.get(
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joaolcorreia/RFM-analysis/master/sample-orders.csv"
        ).text
    )
)
df["order_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["order_date"])

px.line(
    df.assign(
        year=df["order_date"].dt.year,
        month=df["order_date"].dt.month,
        month_name=df["order_date"].dt.strftime("%b"),
    )
    .groupby(["year", "month", "month_name"], as_index=False)
    .agg(value=("grand_total", "sum")),
    x="month_name",
    y="value",
    color="year",
)
```

[image]